# Why is the complement of SAT not in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I know that you cannot give a verification certificate. But, I was just thinking, why can't we give the input to an NDTM deciding SAT, and then reverse the answer? Where is the flaw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually not known whether the complement of SAT is in NP.  If P = NP, then since all P languages are closed under complementation, then the complement of SAT must be in NP (since it's in P).  Otherwise, if the complement of SAT is not in NP, then P ≠ NP by using similar logic.

It's *suspected* that the complement of SAT is not in NP because the complement of SAT consists (ignoring garbage malformed strings) of propositional formulas that are unsatisfiable.  It's unclear what information you could nondeterministically guess that would help you determine whether a formula never evaluates to true, whereas in the case of SAT it's easy to nondeterministically guess a satisfying assignment to check whether a formula is indeed satisfiable.

As for the error in your reasoning - an NTM accepts iff there is *some* accepting branch of the computation.  If you flip all "accepts" to "rejects," then you don't flip the overall result of the computation.  To flip the computation result, you'd have to have the complemented NTM accept iff *every* branch accepts, versus *if at least one* branch accepts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused that suppose I have a NDTM A deciding SAT. And I have a x, which I want to decide if it belongs to SAT complement or not.  I run the input on A and if it accepts(i.e any branch accepted), I reject else if it rejects(i.e all branched rejected), I accept.

Comment: @user96758- If you could run the NDTM to completion and then look at the result, you could indeed flip it.  However, you can't build an NDTM to do that process mechanically.  Try thinking about how that NDTM would work and I think you'll see a problem emerge.

Comment: Yes, maybe I cannot build it but doesn't this whole process make complement SAT to be in NP as I can decide it in non deterministic polynomial time by just running the input on a SAT NDTM.

Comment: @user96758- For the complement of SAT to be in NP, there needs to be a polynomial-time NDTM that decides the complement of SAT.  It's not enough that a human operator equipped with an NDTM could determine whether or not a string is in the complement of SAT; there has to be a single NDTM that decides the complement of SAT with no help from the user.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thanks !